# Правильный синтакис

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, синтаксис

Подскажите правильный синтаксис. Нужно в новый столбец **new** добавить расчитаное значение для **first** и **second** столбца с 2 знаками после запятой. Как я указал ниже выскакивает ошибка. *"f-string: unmatched '['"*

```
df['new'] = f'{(df['first'] / df['second']):.2}'
```

Comment: Если вы внутри кавычек хотите использовать ещё кавычки, то эти кавычки должны быть другими (двойные вместо одинарных, ну или наоборот)

Comment: После исправлений с ковычками, теперь такая ошибка:

**unsupported format string passed to Series.__format__**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Исходная ошибка возникает из-за того, внутри строки используются одинарные кавычки, которой ограничена сама же строка, получается, что `f'{(df['first'] / df['second']):.2}'` эквивалентно таким частям: `f'{(df['` `first` `'] / df['` `second` `']):.2}'`, падает на первой же части, являющейся f-строкой, внутри которой не закрыты все открытые скобки.

Отформатировать колонку целиком через f-строку не получится. Нужно сначала получить значения для новой колонки через `df['first'] / df['second']`, потом каждый элемент отформатировать, после этого уже добавить как новую колонку:

```
df['new'] = (df['first'] / df['second']).apply("{:.2}".format)
```

Аналогично через f-строку, применяемую через лямбду к каждому элементу колонки в отдельности:

```
df['new'] = (df['first'] / df['second']).apply(lambda x: f'{x:.2}')
```

Comment: Ну через `apply(lambda x: ...` наверное можно и `f-строку` применить при желании )

Comment: @insolor ты пулемёт, спасибо!

Comment: @CrazyElf да, добавлю такой вариант